# Javascript get values from database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

I have a html page and a php page.
The html page has a table and the php has a query to a mysql table.
I don't know how to show the query results in my html page.

The html page has the following partial code:

```
<table class="table-striped" id="tabela_editavel_1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Contacto</th>
            <th>Dt Receção</th>
            <th>Dt Validade</th>
            <th>Refª Cliente</th>
            <th>Num Proposta</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="dados_tabela">

        <tr class="">
            <td id="xz"><input id="contacto"/></td>
            <td id="xz"><input id="dtrececao"/></td>
            <td id="xz"><input id="dtvalidade"/></td>
            <td id="xz"><input id="ref_cli"/></td>
            <td id="xz"><input id="numproposta"/></td>
            <td id="xz"><input id="estado"/></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$.getJSON('php/c_listaconsultas.php', function(data) {
  $('#contacto').val(data.nome);
  $('#dtrececao').val(data.datarecepcao);
  $('#dtvalidade').val(data.validadeconsulta);
  $('#ref_cli').val(data.referenciaconsulta);
  $('#numproposta').val(data.propostanumero);
  $('#estado').val(data.estado);            
});
</script>
```

My php file has the code:

```
(...)

mysql_select_db($database_connLOOPGEST, $connLOOPGEST);
$query_rs_listaconsultas = sprintf("SELECT clientes_consultas.id_cliente, clientes_consultas.id_consulta, clientes_consultas.datarecepcao, clientes_consultas.referenciaconsulta, clientes_consultas.validadeconsulta, clientes_consultas.tituloconsulta, loop_propostas.propostanumero, clientes_contactos.nome, loop_propostas.id_proposta, status.descricao estado, clientes.nome_curto nome_cliente FROM (clientes_consultas left join clientes_contactos on clientes_consultas.id_contacto = clientes_contactos.id_contacto) left join loop_propostas on clientes_consultas.id_consulta = loop_propostas.id_consultacliente inner join status on status.id_status = clientes_consultas.estado inner join clientes on clientes.id_cliente = clientes_consultas.id_cliente WHERE clientes_consultas.id_cliente=%s ORDER BY clientes_consultas.datarecepcao DESC", GetSQLValueString($numcliente_rs_listaconsultas, "int"));
$rs_listaconsultas = mysql_query($query_rs_listaconsultas, $connLOOPGEST) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_listaconsultas = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_listaconsultas);
$totalRows_rs_listaconsultas = mysql_num_rows($rs_listaconsultas);

echo json_encode($row_rs_listaconsultas);
```

First of all, my "echo json_encode" doesn't give me all the query rows, but only one, how can a pass all the query rows to my html page? What is missing here? :(((
The second help I need is how can I show those values in my table? I'm using the correct function (.$getJSON)?

Thanks in advance.
Mário

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must iterate over the mysql_fetch_assoc with something like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row_rs[] = $row;
}
```

And the returned data will be an array containing objects. You should iterate over it with:

```
$.each(data, function(element) { /* do something */})
```

Comment: Why iterate when he is just going to encode it? Much better to just fetch all the results. Also, why iterate over the data when you can simply access the properties?

Comment: Radalin, thank you for your answer. I've answered to Nathan, and it is the same for your. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First off, please stop using the `mysql` extension. It is deprecated and you should instead be using `mysqli` or PDO. The reason you're getting only one row is that the function you're using, [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) only returns one row. You want [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) or the [PDO equivalent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). `$.getJSON` is a correct function to use, and setting values like you are should probably work, I would `console.log(data)` to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: Nathan, Thank you for your help. I'm trying to learn something "by my own" and I didn't know about mysqli. Now I read something about it and I will use it. I appreciate your tip, thanks once more. At this moment I'm able to see my data in a table, but now the "search" and the "pagination" of the table are not working it says that my table have "0 rows". I'm using the DataTables and I'm reading about it and passing the corrects (apparently) values (I've checked with console.log(data)). I don't know what is the problem at the moment.